# http_response_timeout filter not working

Tags: plugins, http-api, wp-remote-get, wp-remote-request, wp-remote-post

I am writing a Wordpress plugin that makes calls to external sites. 
I want to raise the timeout for all `wp_remote_*` calls, so I added the following to the `__construct` function of my plugin:

```
add_filter("http_response_timeout", function($timeout) { return 30; });
```

But the calls still time out after 5 seconds. I also tried using a separate function as the second argument, same result. When I pass `array("timeout" => 30)` to the `wp_remote_*` functions directly, it works...

Any idea why the filter is not respected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no filter named "http_response_timeout" in the WordPress core. Where are you finding this filter name from?

The timeout parameter as passed to a wp_remote call has a default of five seconds, and that default can be changed using the "http_request_timeout" filter, which is a different name than you used. Maybe you're just using the wrong word?

Comment: Oh boy, now I feel stupid. I found the filter name here: https://gist.github.com/WerdsWords/6091216 With `http_request_timeout` it works fine. Thanks!